# CSS :hover not working on element with dynamically added class

Tags: css, dynamic, hover

After Dom ready I'm detecting if the mouse moves and attaching a class "has-hover" to a parent div.

Inside it are two labels. The first one has its hover state attached to the "has-hover" class of its parent div, which is the functionality I want to achieve.

The second label has its hover state attached directly to it.

Why does the hover state works on the second label but not in the first one??

Thanks!

```js
function watchForHover() {
 var div = $(".div");
  var hasHoverClass = false;

 function enableHover() {
   if (hasHoverClass) return;
  div.addClass("has-hover");
  hasHoverClass = true;
 };
  
 document.addEventListener("mousemove", enableHover, true);
};

watchForHover();
```

```css
label {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: block;
}
.has-hover {
  label:first-child:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
label:nth-child(2):hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
<label>label 1</label>
<label>label 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like you could simplify your selectors to the following: `.has-hover  label:hover`, and your style rules will apply when hovering over `label` so long as the parent `.div` has the class `.has-hover`

Comment: Thanks @UncaughtTypeError . I used child pseudo selectors just for the sake of the example. If I remove them and just leave there .has-hover selector it wont work either... is there an explanation for that?

Comment: I just tried `.has-hover
 label:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}` in the browser IDE using your code snippet example and it worked as expected. Or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: But did you delete also the `label:hover { opacity: .5; }` selector? It doesn't work for me if i leave just the `.has-hover label:hover { opacity: .5; }` ¿can you make a jsfiddle to show me?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError It worked! I was doing something wrong. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: so what were you doing wrong? You know, for the sake of clarity :)

Comment: This was a simplified version of my problem. After you show me that it really worked I inspect again my original code and found it was I was calling the wrong way some clases in my sass file. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yon can't nest rules in CSS. If you wan't to do that you'll have to use a preprocessor like SASS.

```js
function watchForHover() {
 var div = $(".div");
  var hasHoverClass = false;

 function enableHover() {
   if (hasHoverClass) return;
  div.addClass("has-hover");
  hasHoverClass = true;
 };
  
 document.addEventListener("mousemove", enableHover, true);
};

watchForHover();
```

```css
label {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: block;
}
.has-hover label:first-child:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
label:nth-child(2):hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
<label>label 1</label>
<label>label 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: My fault. I was using SASS but forget to said that. Thanks!